# Fisher's score function has mean zero - what does that even mean?

Tags: likelihood, geometric-distribution, fisher-scoring

I'm trying to follow the [princeton review of likelihood theory](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/a1.pdf).
They define `Fisher’s score function` as The first derivative of the log-likelihood function, and they say that the score is a random vector. E.g for the Geometric distribution:

$$ u(\pi) = n\left(\frac{1}{\pi} - \frac{\bar{y}}{1-\pi} \right) $$

And I can see that it is indeed a function (of the parameter $\pi$), and it is random, as it involves $\bar{y}$.

BUT then they say something I don't understand: "the score evaluated at the true parameter value $\pi$ has mean zero" and they formulate it as $E(u(\pi)) = 0$. What does it mean to evaluate it at the "true parameter value" and then find out its mean? And in the Geometric example, if I use the identity $E(y) = E(\bar{y}) = \frac{1-\pi}{\pi}$ won't I immediately get that $E(u(\pi)) = 0$? what does the "true parameter value" has to do with this?

Comment: Some relevant posts:    http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112451/maximum-likelihood-estimation-mle-in-layman-terms/112480#112480        http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196576/what-kind-of-information-is-fisher-information            http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200946/help-explaining-offering-intuition-examples-of-the-score-function-and-fishers?rq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you pointed out the score function $u$ is, under suitable regularity conditions, defined as "the first derivative of the log-likelihood function".

Let's suppose that $X$ is a random variable with density function $f(x)$. Usually this density changes depending on a vector of parameters $\pi$. Thus it is convenient to wright the density function as $f(x;\pi)$ to make it explicit the dependency on the parameter. We will suppose that the "true" value of $\pi$ for the random variable $X$ is $\pi = \pi_0$. (what I mean is that $X \sim f(\;\cdot\;;\pi_0)$)

The score function can now be written as:
$$u(\pi;x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi}\log f(x;\pi),$$
and it is now clear that it is a function of both $x$ and of $\pi$. (In your question you have $L$ in place of $f$, but there is no difference since the likelihood function is just the density function.)

Consider now the random variable $u(\pi,X)$ and its expectation $\xi(\pi) = \mathbb{E_{\pi_0}}(u(\pi,X))$. Here it is important to notice that the subscript $\pi_0$ is there to indicate the (true) parameter in the distribution of $X$ and diferentiate it from the value $\pi$ with which we are calculating $u$.

Assuming that $f$ is a continuous density (the discrete case is similar) we have:

$$\xi(\pi) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\pi}\log f(x;\pi)\right)f(x;\pi_0)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f'(x;\pi)}{f(x;\pi)}f(x;\pi_0)dx$$

and when you evaluate $\xi$ at the true parameter value $\pi_0$ we get:

$$\xi(\pi_0) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f'(x;\pi_0)}{f(x;\pi_0)}f(x;\pi_0)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f'(x;\pi_0)dx$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x;\pi_0)dx = 0$$

That's the reasoning behind the score function having expectation zero at the true parameter.

You should take a look at books like [this one](https://www.crcpress.com/Introduction-to-the-Theory-of-Statistical-Inference/Liero-Zwanzig/p/book/9781439852927) (chapter 3) to have a bigger understanding of the conditions under which those derivations (like the interchanging of derivative and integral) hold true.

Comment: Thanks! but I'm still not quite sure I see why won't it be 0 if I plug in another value $\pi_1$ ? won't we be able to use the same trick of switching between the integral w.r.t $x$ and the derivative w.r.t. $\pi$?

Comment: $\xi(\pi_1)=\int\frac{f'(x;\pi_1)}{f(x;\pi_1)}f(x;\pi_0)dx$ and now we can't cancel the denominator if $\pi_1\neq\pi_0$.

Comment: another question - in your answer, did you mean the score function for a single **observation** or the score function for the entire **sample** of n observations?

Comment: @ihadanny It makes no difference since you can see your sample as a single realization of a random variable in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: This is the clearest proof I have seen on the issue. Thank you! :)

Comment: Damn, it's a crime how badly this is explained in other places compared to here. The gist of it is that at the true parameter, changing the parameter by a bit is not expected to change the likelihood. If you're in the wrong spot parameter-wise, changing it is expected to change the likelihood.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, thanks to the excellent @Mur1lo answer I now have a better understanding and would like to make my own attempt at making this abstract concept as concrete as I can.

Suppose we have a sample of 5 coin draw results. We assume that they are sampled from a population with Bernoulli distribution with the true parameter $\pi_0$.

When we look at a specific coin draw with result $x_3=1$, we can calculate the **log-likelihood** this patient was sampled from a Bernoulli distribution with all kind of parameter values, e.g. $\pi = 0.2$ or $\pi=0.9$ and so on. so, log-likelihood is a function estimating the likelihood of $x_3$ for each possible value of $\pi$.

$$ LL(\pi|x_3) = x_3ln(\pi) + (1-x_3)ln(1-\pi) $$

Which simply means that if $x_3=1$ the likelihood for that was $\pi$ and if it's 0 the likelihood for that is $1-\pi$.

If we assume independence between the coin draws, then we have an 'average' function representing the log-likelihood of the entire sample of n=5 coin draws.

$$ LL(\pi|X) = \sum{x_i}ln(\pi) + (n-\sum(x_i))ln(1-\pi) $$

We want to find the maximum of $LL(\pi|X)$ - the **mle** = $\pi_{mle}$.

The **score function** $u(\pi)$ is a vector of the derivatives w.r.t each parameter of the log-likelihood. Luckily in our case, it's a simple scalar as there's only one parameter. Under some conditions, it will help us find $\pi_{mle}$, since in that point the score function would be $u(\pi_{mle}) = 0$. We can calculate the **observation score function** for a single observation (coin draw):

$$ u(\pi|x_3) = \frac{x_3}{\pi} - \frac{1-x_3}{1-\pi} $$

and the **sample score function** of n=5 patients:

$$ u(\pi|X) = \frac{\sum{x_i}}{\pi} - \frac{n-\sum{x_i}}{1-\pi} $$

when we set this latest function to 0, we get $\pi_{mle}$.

---

BUT, the specific 5 draws sample has nothing to do with the expectancy of the score function ! The expectancy is the value of the **observation** score function for every possible value of x, multiplied by the probability of that value, which is the density function! In our case, x can take only 2 values: 0 and 1. And the density function is as we assumed is a Bernoulli with parameter $\pi_0$:

$$ E(u(\pi|x_i)) = \sum_x (\frac{x}{\pi} - \frac{1-x}{1-\pi}) \pi_0^x(1-\pi_0)^{1-x} = \frac{\pi_0}{\pi} - \frac{1-\pi_0}{1-\pi}$$

and its clear that it zeros out when evaluated at the true parameter $\pi_0$. The intuitive interpretation is: For each value of $\pi$, what's the mean rate of change in likelihood?

---

The **information matrix** is the variance of the likelihood - how sensitive will our solution be to different data? (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/197471/37793)).

$$I(\pi|x_i) = var(u(\pi|x_i)) = var(\frac{x_i}{\pi} - \frac{1-x_i}{1-\pi}) = var(\frac{x_i-\pi}{\pi(1-\pi)}) = \frac{var(x_i)}{\pi^2(1-\pi)^2} =  \frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{\pi^2(1-\pi)^2}$$

and when evaluated at the true parameter $\pi_0$ it simplifies to:

$$I(\pi_0|x_i) = \frac{1}{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}$$

(see [washington edu notes](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ583/mleLectures.pdf) for more details).

Amazingly, there's another way of measuring how sensitive the likelihood would be in a certain $\pi$! that's the expectancy of the curvature = Hessian = second derivative. The steeper our likelihood, the more accurate we'll be. See details in [mark reid's blog](http://mark.reid.name/blog/fisher-information-and-log-likelihood.html)