# Bernoulli model information matrix - evaluated NOT at the real parameter value?

Tags: likelihood, bernoulli-distribution, fisher-information

related to [Fisher's score function has mean zero - what does that even mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/228601/37793)

I'm trying to follow [eric zivot's maximum likelihood estimation course](http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ583/mleLectures.pdf). I'm looking at page 12, where they compute the information for an observation:

$$I(\pi|x_i) = var(u(\pi|x_i)) = var(\frac{x_i}{\pi} - \frac{1-x_i}{1-\pi}) = var(\frac{x_i-\pi}{\pi(1-\pi)}) = \frac{var(x_i)}{\pi^2(1-\pi)^2} $$

Which I agree with. BUT then they continue and say:

$$ \frac{var(x_i)}{\pi^2(1-\pi)^2}=  \frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{\pi^2(1-\pi)^2} = \frac{1}{1-\pi} $$

I think this is wrong! I think that the Bernoulli model says that there's a true parameter $\pi_0$ from which the observations are sampled, and the information matrix is:

$$ \frac{var(x_i)}{\pi^2(1-\pi)^2}=  \frac{\pi_0(1-\pi_0)}{\pi^2(1-\pi)^2} $$

ONLY when evaluated at the true parameter the information evaluates to:
$ \frac{1}{1-\pi}$.. the same as explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228627/37793) about the expectancy of the score, only this time its variance instead of expectancy.

Am I correct? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've talked with Eric Zivot the author and he confirmed: "I assume pi is the true parameter in the derivation"